# Serve custom commit-msg hook from Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit comes with a default commit message hook to insert a Change-Id in the footer. The hook defines that the Change-Id should be inserted after `Issue` or `Bug` in the footer:

```
CHANGE_ID_AFTER="Bug|Issue"
```

Now I would like to modify this so it becomes:

```
CHANGE_ID_AFTER="Refs|Closes|Fixes"
```

This is because the issue tracker in use doesn't work with `Bug` or `Issue` but with an issue identifier starting with a `#`.

Now of course I can apply this locally but uniformity is desired across the complete development team. It would help a lot if Gerrit would serve this modified file.

I can't seem to find anything in Gerrit's docs that describes what I would like to achieve.
Since the hook is pulled in through [scp](/questions/tagged/scp) I thought I might be able to upload a modified hook the same way. This of course didn't work.

I have administrative rights to Gerrit, so that can't be the issue.

Comment: Hi! or you can store this hook somewhere in the repo. Then everybody can make a symlink to it after pulling it. Once it is done, the hook can be improved mush easier.

Comment: I have also a need for a custom `commit-msg` hook. Probably it's worth filing a feature request in Gerrit's [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/list).

Comment: Gerrit's issue tracker doesn't use `Bug` or `Issue` either, just id numbers.  The format used in the commit message is `Issue: 1234` or `Bug: 5678`.  Just want to mention this in case you weren't aware.